# decode eval function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, eval, decode

I got this a function eval in javascript - http://pastebin.com/E1PXQeKj 
but i don't know how read it? how does this generate or decode the string? 
or simply how is this code?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is unpacker for code encoded in such a way http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker. It seems the only thing this code do is:

```
ver secret = 'dGd3bWw1QWVrUDh1a242dXlNaUFyOVE6MQ';
```

Comment: to tell the truth, correct answer is below (Lekensteyn), and not this one. this eval generates `var secret = 'dEFNLW1QU01JaVZNTWFFN0pWcm9RZkE6MQ';` and you can see this string inside eval's body as `var|secret|\x64\x45\x46...`

Comment: Full analysis below, this kind of encoder is easy. It gets more difficult with recursive operations making intensive use of operator precedence and conditions based on the current state.

Answer (score 5):

Paste it in http://jsbeautifier.org/ and it reveals:

```
var secret = 'dDGSUW1QU01JaVZNTWFFN0pWcm2RZkE6MD';
```

To do it manually, find the end of the eval function and replace `eval` by `alert` or whatever debugging function you use. Line 2 can be handled in that way.

Line 3 formatted looks like:
var _9581

```
;
var _8438 = '196E84D180D984E928C920F980E928D988C652F768E652F680B924F808E924A724E916A872C1000A720A848E872F868D980E864C796E940A724B912F724B732B724B924C876C956D836C912C864A804E1008E840C868A800A740A832E848B680D760F';
var _5668 = /[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;
var _9413 = 2;
var _9565 = _8438.charAt(_8438.length - 1);
var _5032;
var _9978 = _8438.split(_5668);
var _4678 = [String.fromCharCode, isNaN, parseInt, String];
_9978[1] = _4678[_9413 + 1](_4678[_9413](_9978[1]) / 21);
var _6432 = (_9413 == 7) ? String : eval;
_5032 = '';
_11 = _4678[_9413](_9978[0]) / _4678[_9413](_9978[1]);
for (_9581 = 3; _9581 < _11; _9581++) _5032 += (_4678[_9413 - 2]((_4678[_9413](_9978[_9581]) + _4678[_9413](_9978[2]) + _4678[_9413](_9978[1])) / _4678[_9413](_9978[1]) - _4678[_9413](_9978[2]) + _4678[_9413](_9978[1]) - 1));
_6432(_5032);
```

Now analyse it yourself. Care should be taken when something is executeable. Constructs like `foo(bar)`.

Decoding in progress:

```
var _9581;
var _8438 = '196E84D180D984E928C920F980E928D988C652F768E652F680B924F808E924A724E916A872C1000A720A848E872F868D980E864C796E940A724B912F724B732B724B924C876C956D836C912C864A804E1008E840C868A800A740A832E848B680D760F';
var _5668 = /[ABCDEF]/;
var _9413 = 2;
var _9565 = "F";
var _5032;
var _9978 = [196, 84, 180, 984, 928, 920, 980, 928, 988, 652, 768, 652, 680, 924, 808, 924, 724, 916, 872, 1000, 720, 848, 872, 868, 980, 864, 796, 940, 724, 912, 724, 732, 724, 924, 876, 956, 836, 912, 864, 804, 1008, 840, 868, 800, 740, 832, 848, 680, 760, ];
var _4678 = [String.fromCharCode, isNaN, parseInt, String];
_9978[1] = "4"; //String(parseInt(84) / 21)
var _6432 = eval;
_5032 = '';
_11 = 49; //parseInt(196) / parseInt(4);
for (_9581 = 3; _9581 < _11; _9581++) {
    //_5032 += (String.fromCharCode((parseInt(_9978[_9581]) + parseInt(180) + parseInt(4)) / parseInt(4) - parseInt(180) + parseInt(4) - 1));
    _5032 += String.fromCharCode((parseInt(_9978[_9581]) + 184) / 4 - 177);
}
// so from here one, we can safely assume that the code is NOT executable
//_6432(_5032);
console.log(_5032);
```

Yields:

```
secret = 'dGd3bWw1QWVrUDh2a412dXl2aUFyOVE6MQ';
```

Conclusion:

- The first packer is to confuse people who manage to decode it.
- The second code actually changes the `secret` variable

Comment: Analysed it correctly now, perhaps a parser can turn such numbers in words like `apple` and `banana`, which makes the analysis much easier.

Comment: @David: if it's really that secret, you should change anything that uses this secret immediately as it's available in public (see [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6264010/revisions)).

Comment: would you mind to give this code a try?http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/31521061